Type Error after running node dist/server.js in Next Js
npm run start

> project@0.1.0 start
> node dist/server.js

/home/root/Documents/project/dist/server.js:45
var app = (0, next_1.default)({ dev: dev, hostname: hostname, port: port });
                             ^

TypeError: (0 , next_1.default) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/root/Documents/project/dist/server.js:45:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Can anyone explain me how to resolve this issue , I am trying to build my Next Js application written in typescript so that i can host it on my shared hosting as a node js application.
